# Get last 30 day records from today date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have small question about SQL Server: how to get last 30 days information from this table

Sample data:

`Product`:

```
Pdate
----------
2014-11-20
2014-12-12
2014-11-10
2014-12-13
2014-10-12
2014-11-15
2014-11-14
2014-11-16
2015-01-18
```

Based on this table data i want output like below

```
pdate
-------
2014-11-20
2014-12-12
2014-12-13
2014-11-16
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
WHERE pdate >= DATEADD(day, -30, getdate()).
```

but it now give exactly result. Please tell me how to solve this issue in SQL Server

Comment: What is the problem with your query? How `2015-01-18` is in output.

Comment: no need to dispaly  this 2015-01-18 record its not a last 30 days to today.

Answer (score 93):

Add one more condition in `where clause`

```
SELECT * FROM  product 
WHERE pdate >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE()) 
and   pdate <= getdate()
```

Or use `DateDiff`

```
SELECT * FROM  product 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,pdate,GETDATE()) between 0 and 30
```

Comment: thanks.give logic working fine.we may give between 0 and 29 that time its take from today to last 30 days.

Comment: @user3457912 - No it should be from 0 to 30. for today datediff will be 0

Answer (score 22):

You can use `DateDiff` for this. The where clause in your query would look like:

```
where DATEDIFF(day,pdate,GETDATE()) < 31
```

Answer (score 14):

I dont know why all these complicated answers are on here but this is what I would do

```
where pdate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -30
```

OR `WHERE CAST(PDATE AS DATE) >= GETDATE() -30`

Comment: Works for Oracle, DATEDIFF didn't

Comment: Also worked for redash. The other solutions didn't.

Answer (score 6):

Below query is appropriate for the last 30 days records

Here, I have used a review table and `review_date` is a column from the review table

```
SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE DATE(review_date) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Answer (score 4):

This Should Work Fine

```
SELECT * FROM product 
WHERE pdate BETWEEN datetime('now', '-30 days') AND datetime('now', 'localtime')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to get the data of the last 30 days, based on a column.

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(dateColumn, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
```