# computing a date that is "x" business days from a particular date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have date field called "blackout begin date " in SQL server and I need to subtract 3 days  from this date fields (to show three days ago from this specific date). I wrote below but i didnt get my desire answer, can you tell me what I doing wrong?

```
select 
datediff(day, T.blackout_begin_date, getdate()) as Blackout_Datediff
from blackout 
where 
datediff(day, getdate(), T.blackout_begin_date) > 3
```

Comment: If you want to subtract 3 days from a date, you use `DATEADD(day, -3, somedate)` not datediff. Fun side note, you can also do `somedate - 3.0` in some cases

Comment: "i didnt get my desire answer" is not a problem description! What answer _did_ you get, why was that wrong, and what should it be instead, with an explanation of the logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get last 30 day records from today date in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479856/get-last-30-day-records-from-today-date-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
   select 
    datediff(day, T.blackout_begin_date, getdate()) as Blackout_Datediff
    from blackout 
    where 
   cast(t.blackout_begin_date as date ) >= cast(getdate()-3) as date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #DateList ([Date] datetime)

declare @baseDate datetime, @offset int, @newDate datetime

select @baseDate = '2010-01-01', @offset = 1

select @baseDate
insert into #DateList 
select @baseDate

set @newDate = @baseDate

select @newDate
while @offset < 10000 -- set this to whatever you want
begin
  set @newDate = @newDate  + 1
  if (select datepart(dw, @newDate)) not in (1, 7)
  begin
  insert into #DateList
  select @newDate
  set @offset = @offset + 1
  end
  else 
  begin 
  set @offset = @offset + 1
  end
end

select max(b.blackout_begin_date)
from #DateList d
join blackout b on cast(d.[date] as date) = cast(b.blackout_begin_date as date)
where cast(b.blackout_begin_date as date) <= cast(getdate() - 3 as date)
```

Can add a >=getdate() -5 filter if you need a specific date as well

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is "DATEADD(day, -3, somedate)"
+1 for @Caius Jard answer