# Mysql query record customer and last activity older than 30 days

Tags: mysql

this is my table
[image]

I wish to query the customer that didn't have any record within 30days

I try this query

```
SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%d/%Y') 
    FROM transaction 
    WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
AND type = 'deposit'
    ORDER BY trans_id DESC
```

but it will return all the data older than 30 days,

[image]

my aim is to get the user who have no new record within 30 days, so it should only show testuser2

how can I make it?

Comment: Your Complete Answer is available here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479856/get-last-30-day-records-from-today-date-in-sql-server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get last 30 day records from today date in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479856/get-last-30-day-records-from-today-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: tbh no, I can get all the data older than 30 day , but actually the customer fangfang94 have the other record within 30 day, I want to get the data which customer + date have no new record in 30 day.

I am trying to explain as clear as I can, sorry if cause any misunderstanding

Comment: *I wish to query the customer that didn't have any record within 30days* If you need customer only then why you try to get the whole row??? `SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM ...` will solve.

Comment: Because I gonna send the data to my table

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a left join on the customer with transcation <= 30 anche check for not matching values

```
SELECT t1.*,DATE_FORMAT(t1.date, '%m/%d/%Y') 
    FROM transaction t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT customer FROM transaction 
    WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
) t2 ON t2customer = t1.customer
WHERE t1.date <= DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
AND t1.type = 'deposit'
AND t2.customer  IS NULL
ORDER BY trans_id DESC
```

Comment: after I use your query it return 0 results
is there I missing something?

I change t2 ON t2customer -> t2 ON t2.customer because it return
#1054 - Unknown column 't2customer' in 'on clause'

Comment: answer updated . .wrong NULL compare (= null instead of  is NULL)